# How to decrease button size?

Tags: gnome, themes, button

I am using the **Sierra** theme. Everything is alright, but except the button size in eclipse.

[image: see this picture]

See that image? all of the button's height is larger than the text box. It obviously doesn't look good, so I want to decrease the height of these buttons. So I have tried to edit the gtk.css file:

```
button {
  min-height: 20px; /* ********** I have changed this value only, nothing else ********** */
  min-width: 16px;
  transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  color: #242424;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.04), 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.01), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}
```

But I cannot make the height of the button equal to the height of the text box.

[image: see this picture]

No matter how much I reduce the value of ***min-height***, the button remains larger than the text box.

So, how can I reduce the height of the button equal to the height of the text box? Should I edit another line of *gtk.css*? (I need to edit only buttons, nothing else)

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this GitHub page](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme/issues/452) for a user with a similar issue, the rest of this answer will be citing that source.

The example base code they gave was the following

```
button {
        min-height: 22px;
        min-width: 24px;
        @include button(shade($bg_color, 1.2), $fg_color);

        .inline-toolbar &,
        .linked > & { @include linked_button(shade($bg_color, 1.2)); }

        .linked.vertical > & { @include linked_vertical_button(shade($bg_color, 1.2)); }

        &.circular { // FIXME: aggregate to buttons
            border-radius: 20px;
            -gtk-outline-radius: 20px;

            label { padding: 0; }
        }
    }
```

Notice the 2 first lines, `min-height` and `min-width` You say that you have only changed height as of now, however, if there are options enabled in the theme to lock buttons to a certain ratio (usually to prevent text wrapping), you will need to change both height and width to see an effect:

```
button {
        min-height: 11px;
        min-width: 12px;
        @include button(shade($bg_color, 1.2), $fg_color);

        .inline-toolbar &,
        .linked > & { @include linked_button(shade($bg_color, 1.2)); }

        .linked.vertical > & { @include linked_vertical_button(shade($bg_color, 1.2)); }

        &.circular { // FIXME: aggregate to buttons
            border-radius: 20px;
            -gtk-outline-radius: 20px;

            label { padding: 0; }
        }
    }
```

A couple more comments on the page;

> Setting min height-width below 16px should resolve the issue. But this calls for trial and error.

---

> Try using min height/width = 16/14 or 14/12 and then try optimizing. Everything should change proportionally.

The changelog of the page itself indicates this is a problem that was never really resolved, there was more so a workaround developed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, but button is still larger than text field. I have tried changing both height and width, I have tried some combination of height and width but no luck. button size decreased, but not the same as text field :(